# Set picker default no clickable value as title

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, picker

I'm trying to develop a `Picker` with a field that corresponds to the title. The problem is that I'm not understanding how to use the title field of the `Picker` view.

This is the code. The problem is that the `Picker` is taking as title the `string "Spain"`. Instead I want the title `"Select country"` which is visible until the user select a field.

[image: First things that the user see]

[image: View once the user press the Picker]

```
struct CustomPicker: View {
    
    @State private var selection = "Select country"
    let colors = ["Spain", "France"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4, content: {
    
            HStack(spacing: 15) {
                
                Picker("Select country", selection: $selection) {
                    ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(DefaultPickerStyle())
            }
            
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        })
            .frame(height: 50)
            .background(.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't come standard with SwiftUI. You would have to custom make your UI for this (and that might not be hard). Depending on how much you're willing to compromise, you can have what you want with a slight tweak of your code. This is what a picker looks like within a List (as well as your Picker in the List).

To do this I modified your code slightly to include an enum for the countries.

```
enum Country: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case spain, france, germany, switzerland
    var id: Self { self }
}

struct CustomPicker: View {
    
    @State private var selection: Country = .spain
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Picker("Select Country", selection: $selection) {
                    ForEach(Country.allCases, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0.rawValue.capitalized)
                            .tag($0)
                    }
                }
                Picker("Select Country", selection: $selection) {
                    ForEach(Country.allCases, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0.rawValue.capitalized)
                            .tag($0)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.menu)
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationTitle("Country Picker")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: showing different Picker styles within a List]

Comment: I think that the selection with the navigation is the best. It is possible to have the first selection field not in a list? Because it represent just a single filed of many fields. [current situation](https://imgur.com/a/7efPoYr)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your picker before loop through the items, you can add a Text() with tag(-1) which make it first Item

```
 Picker("Select Country", selection: $selection) {
                    Text("Select")
                        .tag(-1)
                    ForEach(Country.allCases, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0.rawValue.capitalized)
                            .tag($0)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.menu)
```